# Calculation of the pH of a mixture of a strong acid and weak acid

Tags: equilibrium, ph

The question is to find out the $\mathrm{pH}$ of a mixture of weak acid and strong acid. My book just states the formula as $$\mathrm{pH}=-\log 
\frac{C_2+\sqrt{C_2^2+4K_\mathrm{a}C_1}}{2}$$

where $C_1$ is the concentration (in mole/litre) of the weak acid (ionisation constant $K_\mathrm{a}$), and $C_2$ is that of the strong acid.

I understand that the strong acid will dissociate completely and the weak acid will dissociate with an ionisation constant. So the $\ce{H+}$ ion concentration from strong acid will be simply $C_2$ and that from weak acid will be $\sqrt{K_\mathrm{a}C_1}$. But I could not derive the above formula for the $\mathrm{pH}$ using these facts. I need help here.

Comment: can anyone point out which book that provides the stated equation? thank you in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chemical thermodynamics is easy in that it always has enough equations to derive all the variables involved, and guarantees to produce a unique solution. The derivation itself may be not that easy, but that's another story.

In short, we have some weak acid $\ce{HA}$ and the products of its dissociation. Mind you, $\ce{H+}$ comes also from the strong acid, which dissociates completely. Now, the equations:

$$\ce{[HA] + [A-] = }C_1 \tag1$$
$$\ce{[H+]=[A-]}+C_2 \tag2$$
$${\ce{[H+][A-]}\over\ce{[HA]}} = K_\mathrm{a} \tag3$$

Is the rest clear?

> Use the equation $(2)$ to exclude $\ce{[A-]}$, then use the equation $(1)$ to exclude $\ce{[HA]}$, and end up with a quadratic equation on $\ce{H+}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.can you please explain how you wrote down first two equations.

Comment: Well, the first one is just the conservation law: the summary concentration of protonated and deprotonated forms of HA is always the same, for it can't be created or destroyed. The second is charge conservation: for every H+, there is an A- or the other anion.

Comment: Nope. I used A for the anion of the **weak** acid. The strong acid I didn't identify at all, because why would I?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I derive this formula according to your method :$$\mathrm{pH}=-\log 
\frac{-(K_a-C_2)+\sqrt{(K_a-C_2)^2+4K_\mathrm{a}(C_1+C_2)}}{2}$$

Comment: I try to approximate the above formula as:$$\mathrm{pH}=-\log 
\frac{C_2+\sqrt{C_2^2+4K_\mathrm{a}(C_1+C_2)}}{2}$$ Is it right?

Comment: First formula is OK. Second formula is OK if Ka is negligibly low compared to C2, but in that case it can be simplified further.

Comment: @IvanNeretin thank you.How can be simplified further?

Comment: Ignore the dissociation of the weak acid altogether.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

-The above workup should be pretty easy to understand.

-The only tough task is to understand the approximation in 3rd last step.

Comment: Ivan's answer was sufficient.

Comment: He just gave hints.The above answer is complete workup.

Comment: The answer was accepted which means the OP was able to do the working himself. It's just about solving a quadratic.

Comment: Hey Ritwik, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately though, most of what you wrote is already covered by Ivan's answer. Only a quadratic equation needed to be solved, as Abcd also said. The only new thing I see is a simple statement: "$K_1<C_2$ (magnitude wise)". Perhaps, that was better suited as a comment on Ivan's answer instead? || Also, we support mathjax on our site. You needn't paste photos of math expressions, head over [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here?noredirect=1&lq=1) to learn more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that this formula is applicable only if the acid constant of the weak acid is indeed much smaller than the concentration of the H3O+ ions formed in the protolyzation of the strong acid. This is because the formula uses the approximation K1 << C2 in the derivation.

For example, if:

$$ K_1 = 5 \cdot 10^{-2}, $$

and the

$$ C_2 = 0.01 M, $$

then the suggested formula is not valid, which is obviously because the used approximation (K1 << C2) does not hold.